# Installing peerDependencies of nested dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, dependencies, npm-install

I have a project dependency structure like this:

```
Project A
   |_______>Webpack@^1.0.0
   |_______>Project B
               |_________>Webpack@^3.0.0
               |_________>extract-text-webpack-plugin@^3.0.1
                              |____________>has a peerDependency of webpack@^3.1.0
```

When I do `npm install` in `Project A`, this is my node_modules structure:

```
Project A/node_modules  ->  Webpack 1.15.0
                        ->  extract-text-webpack-plugin 3.0.2
                        ->  Project B
Project B/node_modules  ->  Webpack 3.12.0
```

Now if I try to use `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, it gives a webpack related error because its peer is `Webpack 1.15.0` whereas it requires a peer dependency of `webpack@^3.0.1`.

How can I make sure that `extract-text-webpack-plugin` gets installed in Project B's node_modules where I have its peer dependency installed.

I tried using `npm dedupe` (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe) in Project A to instead get `Webpack 3.12.0` into Project A's node_modules folder, but it didnt move `Webpack 3.12.0` outside.

Is there a way to handle this case?